# Really new to RUBY and would appreciate some guidance

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to def random_both in order to call both a random_case and a random_name and I think I'm just messing up the syntax to call it right, I'm super new to Ruby and am just really frustrated by this as it feels like it should be simple.

```
def upper(string)
  string.upcase
end

def lower(string)
 string.downcase
end

def random_name
 ["Ollie", "Ana"].sample
end

def random_case(string)
 [upper(string), lower(string)].sample
end

**def random_both
  return random_name
  return random_case
end**

puts "My name is #{random_both()}"
```

Comment: In terms of both time and space, it would be more efficient to write `def random_case(str); str.public_send([:upcase, :downcase].sample); end`.

Comment: ...or `if [:up, :dn].sample == :up; str.upcase; else; str.downcase; end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want:

```
def random_both
  random_case(random_name)
end
```

It calls `random_name` and passes that value (i.e. either `"Ollie"` or `"Ana"`) to `random_case` which turns it into its uppercase or lowercase variant:

```
random_both #=> "OLLIE"
random_both #=> "ollie"
random_both #=> "ANA"
random_both #=> "OLLIE"
random_both #=> "ana"
```

Comment: Thanks both, I had literally been working on this for like 45 minutes, I can't publicly upvote either answer, but they were both really useful and as soon as I saw them it made total sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can only return once from a function, so your `random_both` will return `random_name`, and then it's done. You're also calling `random_case` without an argument in `random_both`.

Consider building your string before you return it, something like this, perhaps:

```
def random_both
  name = random_name
  name_cased = random_case(name)
  "#{name} #{name_cased}"
end
```

In ruby, parens `()` are optional, and the return is implicit, so you don't need to use them explicitly.

[Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-function-method-syntax/) is an explanation on how functions work.

Comment: Thanks you for the really clear explanation, it is really useful to see it laid out this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this using below simple code

```
def random_name
  ['Ollie', 'Ana'].sample 
end

def random_case(string)
  [string.upcase, string.downcase].sample
end

def random_both 
  random_case(random_name) 
end

10.times{ puts "My name is #{random_both}"  }
```

output

```
My name is ANA
My name is OLLIE
My name is ANA
My name is ana
My name is ana
My name is ollie
My name is OLLIE
My name is ana
My name is ollie
My name is ollie
```

if you want to see advanced use of ruby you can do like below

```
def random_both 
  %w[Ollie Ana].sample
               .send(%i[upcase downcase].sample)
               .prepend('My name is ')
end

10.times{ puts random_both }
```

output

```
My name is ollie
My name is ANA
My name is OLLIE
My name is ollie
My name is ANA
My name is ANA
My name is OLLIE
My name is ollie
My name is ollie
My name is ANA
```